# Create an instance of IHubContext<MyClass> in a webjob with Simple Injector

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, simple-injector, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using .NET Core 2.2 and SignalR Core and I need to inject `IHubContext<MyClass>` via Simple Injector in my Webjob.

It works perfectly in my web app but when I'm trying to reach my service via web job, it's complaining about lacking injection of `IHubContext<IHubContext<BroadcastHub>>`

I need a way to register it via Simple Injector

This is my `Configuration` in Program.cs file in my Webjob

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using Gateway.BLL.BaseClasses;
using Gateway.BLL.Config;
using Gateway.BLL.Services;
using Gateway.BLL.Services.Interfaces;
using Gateway.BLL.SignalR;
using Gateway.Model.MappingProfiles;
using Gateway.Repository;
using Gateway.Repository.Interfaces;
using Gateway.Repository.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SimpleInjector;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Gateway.WebJob
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var container = new Container();

            DbContextOptionsBuilder ob = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();

            var config = new MapperConfiguration
                (cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new ModelMappingProfile());
            }
                );
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();

            ServiceCollection sr = new ServiceCollection();

            sr.AddSignalR();


            var serviceProvider = sr.AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
            var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();

            IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            // Duplicate here any configuration sources you use.
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            var medchartApiConfiguration = new MedchartApiConfiguration();
            configuration.Bind("MedchartApiConfiguration", medchartApiConfiguration);

            var serviceBusConfiguration = new ServiceBusConfiguration();
            configuration.Bind("ServiceBusConfiguration", serviceBusConfiguration);

            ob = ob.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionString:GatewayDB"]);

            IMemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());

            ConfigureServices(sr);

            var builder = new HostBuilder();
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddServiceBus(o =>
                {
                    o.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = true;
                    o.MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 10;
                    o.ConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://gatewayqueue.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=admin;SharedAccessKey=Wd2YwCEJT2g3q4ykvdOIU2251YD5FizCn5aCuumzdz4=";
                }).AddSignalR();
            });
            builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConsole();
                string instrumentationKey = context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
                {
                    b.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o => o.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey);
                }
            });

            builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
                //services.AddHttpClient();
                //hostContext.Configuration.Bind("MedchartApiConfiguration", medchartApiConfiguration);
                //services.AddSingleton(medchartApiConfiguration);
                services.AddSingleton(container);
                services.AddScoped<JobActivator.ScopeDisposable>();
                services.AddScoped<IJobActivator, JobActivator>();
            });

            container.Register<IPatientService, PatientService>();
            container.Register<IPatientRepository, PatientRepository>();
            container.Register<IProviderService, ProviderService>();
            container.Register<IPatientGroupProviderRepository, PatientGroupProviderRepository>();
            container.Register<IPatientGroupRepository, PatientGroupRepository>();
            container.Register<IConsentRepository, ConsentRepository>();
            container.Register<IHttpClientWrapper, HttpClientWrapper>();
            container.Register<IMedchartService, MedchartService>();
            container.Register<IGroupRepository, GroupRepository>();
            container.Register<IReportRepository, ReportRepository>();
            container.Register<IProviderRepository, ProviderRepository>();
            container.RegisterSingleton(httpClientFactory);
            container.RegisterSingleton(memoryCache);
            container.RegisterSingleton(medchartApiConfiguration);
            container.RegisterSingleton(serviceBusConfiguration);
            container.Register<ILoggerFactory>(() => loggerFactory, Lifestyle.Singleton);
            container.RegisterSingleton(configuration);
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<PatientRepository>), typeof(Logger<PatientRepository>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<PatientService>), typeof(Logger<PatientService>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<HttpClientWrapper>), typeof(Logger<HttpClientWrapper>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<MedchartService>), typeof(Logger<MedchartService>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<ProviderService>), typeof(Logger<ProviderService>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<ProviderRepository>), typeof(Logger<ProviderRepository>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<ReportRepository>), typeof(Logger<ReportRepository>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(mapper);
            container.Register<GatewayDBContext>(() => {
                var options = ob.Options;
                return new GatewayDBContext(options);
            });

            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                host.Run();
            }
        }

        private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddTransient<Functions, Functions>();
            services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my simplified Service that is using SignalR: (this is another project that webjob will use it

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Gateway.BLL.SignalR;

// namespace Gateway.BLL.Services
public class PatientService : HttpClientWrapper, IPatientService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<BroadcastHub> _hubContext;

    public PatientService(IHubContext<BroadcastHub> hubContext)
        : base(logger,httpClientFactory,medchartConfig)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public async Task<OutputHandler<IEnumerable<PatientEnrollmentParams>>>
        CreatePatientAsync(List<PatientEnrollmentParams> patients,
            CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var result = new OutputHandler<IEnumerable<PatientEnrollmentParams>>();
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("BroadcastMessage");
        return result;
    } 
}
```

this is my webjob that will call PatientService in another project

```cs
    using Gateway.BLL.Config;
using Gateway.BLL.Processors;
using Gateway.BLL.Queues;
using Gateway.BLL.Services;
using Gateway.Model.Queues;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SimpleInjector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gateway.WebJob
{
    public class Functions
    {
        private Container _container;
        public Functions(Container container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public async Task ProcessEnrollmentStatus([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusConfiguration:EnrollmentMessage:QueueName%")]string message, ILogger log)
        {
            var _patientService = _container.GetInstance<IPatientService>();
            GetEnrollmentStatusTaskProcessor processor = new GetEnrollmentStatusTaskProcessor(_patientService);
            EnrollmentStatusTask data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EnrollmentStatusTask>(message);
            await processor.Process(data);
        }

        public async Task ProcessConsentRequestStatus([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusConfiguration:ConsentRequestMessage:QueueName%")]string message, ILogger log)
        {
            var _patientService = _container.GetInstance<IPatientService>();
            GetConsentRequestTaskProcessor processor = new GetConsentRequestTaskProcessor(_patientService);
            ConsentRequestTask data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConsentRequestTask>(message);
            await processor.Process(data);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the process method that will call patientService:

```cs
    using Gateway.BLL.Services;
using Gateway.Model.Queues;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gateway.BLL.Processors
{
    public class GetEnrollmentStatusTaskProcessor :  IProcessor<EnrollmentStatusTask>
    {
        private IPatientService _patientService;

        public GetEnrollmentStatusTaskProcessor(IPatientService patientService)
        {
            _patientService = patientService;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Process(EnrollmentStatusTask data)
        {
            bool updated = await _patientService.UpdatePatientEnrollmentStatus(data.PatientId, data.PatientMedchartId.ToString(), data.GroupId);
            return updated;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to register `IHubContext<MyClass>` in my webjob in program.cs but I'm not able to register it via the following ways:

```cs
hubContext = serviceProvider.GetService<IHubContext<BroadcastHub>>();
container.RegisterSingleton(hubContext);
```

or this way

```cs
container.Register<IHubContext<BroadcastHub>>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Update 2019-12-02:
I was able to resolve IHubContext but now i'm receiving e new issue. this is my function class:

```cs
    using Gateway.BLL.Config;
using Gateway.BLL.Processors;
using Gateway.BLL.Queues;
using Gateway.BLL.Services;
using Gateway.Model.Queues;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SimpleInjector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gateway.WebJob
{
    public class Functions
    {
        private Container _container;
        public Functions(Container container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public async Task ProcessEnrollmentStatus([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusConfiguration:EnrollmentMessage:QueueName%")]string message, ILogger log)
        {
            var _patientService = _container.GetInstance<IPatientService>();
            GetEnrollmentStatusTaskProcessor processor = new GetEnrollmentStatusTaskProcessor(_patientService);
            EnrollmentStatusTask data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EnrollmentStatusTask>(message);
            await processor.Process(data);
        }

        public async Task ProcessConsentRequestStatus([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusConfiguration:ConsentRequestMessage:QueueName%")]string message, ILogger log)
        {
            var _patientService = _container.GetInstance<IPatientService>();
            GetConsentRequestTaskProcessor processor = new GetConsentRequestTaskProcessor(_patientService);
            ConsentRequestTask data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConsentRequestTask>(message);
            await processor.Process(data);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my progrm.cs class after all updates:

```cs
    using AutoMapper;
using Gateway.BLL.BaseClasses;
using Gateway.BLL.Config;
using Gateway.BLL.Services;
using Gateway.BLL.Services.Interfaces;
using Gateway.BLL.SignalR;
using Gateway.Model.MappingProfiles;
using Gateway.Repository;
using Gateway.Repository.Interfaces;
using Gateway.Repository.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SimpleInjector;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Gateway.WebJob
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var container = new Container();

            DbContextOptionsBuilder ob = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();

            var config = new MapperConfiguration
                (cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new ModelMappingProfile());
            }
                );
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();

            ServiceCollection sr = new ServiceCollection();
            sr.AddLogging();
            sr.AddSignalR();

            sr.AddDbContextPool<GatewayDBContext>(options => { /*options */ });

            sr.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
             {
                 options.AddLogging();
                 //options.CrossWire<ILoggerFactory>();
             });

            sr.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true).UseSimpleInjector(container);


            var serviceProvider = sr.AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
            var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();

            IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            // Duplicate here any configuration sources you use.
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            var medchartApiConfiguration = new MedchartApiConfiguration();
            configuration.Bind("MedchartApiConfiguration", medchartApiConfiguration);

            var serviceBusConfiguration = new ServiceBusConfiguration();
            configuration.Bind("ServiceBusConfiguration", serviceBusConfiguration);

            ob = ob.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionString:GatewayDB"]);

            IMemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());

            ConfigureServices(sr);

            var builder = new HostBuilder();
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddServiceBus(o =>
                {
                    o.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = true;
                    o.MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 10;
                    o.ConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://gatewayqueue.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=admin;SharedAccessKey=Wd2YwCEJT2g3q4ykvdOIU2251YD5FizCn5aCuumzdz4=";
                });
            });
            builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConsole();
                b.Services.AddLogging();
                string instrumentationKey = context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
                {
                    b.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o => o.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey);
                }
            });

            builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                //services.AddHttpClient();
                //hostContext.Configuration.Bind("MedchartApiConfiguration", medchartApiConfiguration);
                //services.AddSingleton(medchartApiConfiguration);
                //services.AddSingleton(container);
                //services.AddScoped<JobActivator.ScopeDisposable>();
                //services.AddScoped<IJobActivator, JobActivator>();
            });

            container.Register<IPatientService, PatientService>();
            container.Register<IPatientRepository, PatientRepository>();
            container.Register<IProviderService, ProviderService>();
            container.Register<IPatientGroupProviderRepository, PatientGroupProviderRepository>();
            container.Register<IPatientGroupRepository, PatientGroupRepository>();
            container.Register<IConsentRepository, ConsentRepository>();
            container.Register<IHttpClientWrapper, HttpClientWrapper>();
            container.Register<IMedchartService, MedchartService>();
            container.Register<IGroupRepository, GroupRepository>();
            container.Register<IReportRepository, ReportRepository>();
            container.Register<IProviderRepository, ProviderRepository>();
            container.RegisterSingleton(httpClientFactory);
            container.RegisterSingleton(memoryCache);
            container.RegisterSingleton(medchartApiConfiguration);
            container.RegisterSingleton(serviceBusConfiguration);
            //container.Register<ILoggerFactory>(() => loggerFactory, Lifestyle.Singleton);
            container.RegisterSingleton(configuration);
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<PatientRepository>), typeof(Logger<PatientRepository>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<PatientService>), typeof(Logger<PatientService>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<HttpClientWrapper>), typeof(Logger<HttpClientWrapper>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<MedchartService>), typeof(Logger<MedchartService>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<ProviderService>), typeof(Logger<ProviderService>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<ProviderRepository>), typeof(Logger<ProviderRepository>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger<ReportRepository>), typeof(Logger<ReportRepository>));
            container.RegisterSingleton(mapper);
            //container.Register<GatewayDBContext>(() =>
            //{
            //    var options = ob.Options;
            //    return new GatewayDBContext(options);
            //});
            container.Verify();
            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                host.Run();
            }
        }

        private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddTransient<Functions, Functions>();
            services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting this error that it means the container inside the function class is not resolved:

```
fail: Host.Results[0]
```

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'SimpleInjector.Container' while attempting to activate 'Gateway.WebJob.Functions'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs:line 37
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:line 44
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ParameterHelper.Initialize() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 846
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsyncCore(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 117

Comment: Hi Alireza, in order to help you, would you mind posting more information? Please provide the following details: 1) information on what technologies you are using (is this SignalR, SignalR Core, .NET, .NET Core, etc). 2) In case of an error, provide the full exception details (i.e. message, type, and stack trace of the exception and all its inner exceptions). 3) Provide a fully functional, but minimal example that demonstrates the problem. 4) explain what you've tried thus far.

Comment: @Steven I updated the post. thank you

Comment: The [Simple Injector integration guide](https://simpleinjector.org/integration#other-technologies) contains a link to [GitHub page](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/631) that describes how to integrate with SignalR Core. Did you follow this guide in combination with the normal [ASP.NET Core integration guide](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore)? Please update your question to show a minimal, reproducible example based on those documents, and please (always) add *full exception information* that includes exception types, exception messages, and full stack traces.

Comment: Thank you steven, I'll update it but before that maybe answer to this question resolves my issue. I need a way from simple Injector to create an instance of IHubContext<MYCLASS>. I didn't find any document that shows how can I create an instance of IHubContext<MyClass> which MyClass is Hub.

Comment: @Steven I updated the question and added the exception, please check. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out myself, but as long as "auto cross wiring" is enabled in the Simple Injector integration (which is the default), you should be able to get `IHubContext<T>` implementations injected without having to do anything.

Here's an example startup class:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    private readonly Container container = new Container();
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // default asp stuff here

        // add signalr
        services.AddSignalR();

        // add simple injector (enables auto cross wiring)
        services.AddSimpleInjector(this.container, options =>
        {
            options.AddAspNetCore().AddControllerActivation();
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSimpleInjector(container);

        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

And here's a hub context injected into a controller that is created by Simple Injector:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> context;

    public HomeController(IHubContext<MyHub> context, Container container)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't have any issue in my web app. It works same as you described. I have this issue in my webjob after I run my webjob. I updated my question and included the exception. I appreciate your help

Comment: Hi Alireza. Nowhere in your example I see calls to `services.AddSimpleInjector` and `provider.UseSimpleInjector`. Without these calls, Simple Injector will *not* cross wire framework instances. Please follow the [integration guide](https://simpleinjector.org/servicecollection).

Comment: Please post full exception details.

Comment: I added Container.Verify() and I received a more descriptive error. I updated the post. please check the last section. Thank you

Comment: I fixed the issue based on your help and now Container.Verify() passes but I'm getting another error could you please take a look? i updated the post. Thank you

Comment: now the exact error is: I'm trying to inject container to another class in the constructor but it's not resolved by simple injector that's why I receive the error.

Comment: Thank you @Steven for your help. i fixed it.